# Validate user password before signup or edit

Tags: javascript, validation, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, before-save

I'm trying to validate the user password before signing up or changing it successfully.
For instance, I want to force the user to have at least 6 chars in his/her password.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function (request, response) {

  var user = request.object;

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  if (user.isNew() || user.dirty("password")) {

    var regex = /^(.{6,})$/; //at least six characters

    if (!regex.test(user.get("password"))) {
      response.error("Password does not fit the requirements");
      return;
    }
  } 

  if ((user.isNew() || user.dirty("email")) && !user.getEmail()) {
    response.error("Email is empty");
    return;
  }

  response.success();

});
```

So, even with the Master Key I cannot validate the password. 
**Update**: The call `user.get("password")` returns `undefined` the whole time.

One way around would be to create a cloud function to validate the password but then it is up to the clients to validate the password before calling the signup. I wanted to put that in a `beforeSave` of `Parse.User`

Comment: The question doesn't indicate what's not working.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @danh . Question properly updated.

Answer (score 0):

The edit was very helpful in spotting the problem.  It would stand to reason that `user.get("password")` would return the user's password, but the `Parse.User` object provides special methods for username, password, and email.  Replace with `user.password`.

[See the doc here.](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users)

Comment: I guess those parameters are more useful for a client rather than the cloud code. Still, the `user.password` returns `undefined` . If I had to guess I would say it is for security reasons.

Comment: Yes - My code does something like this on the client, before signup, and its possible that by the time beforeSave fires, the password obfuscation is done already.  You can move the password test to the client before signup.  Also, I think empty email is caught for you by parse.

Comment: Regarding the email, it doesn't. If I provide an invalid email it throws an error but if it goes empty it is recorded empty.
About the password, my goal was to validate on the server so the client is forced to be well implemented.

Comment: Ok.  Another idea is a cloud function called miguelSignup that precedes the signup with a password check.  You'll want the user on return to become the current user.  (see docs for Parse.User.become https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.User.html#.become)